# multiple URL redirect htaccess with POST data

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

In my project for REST API older version I have multiple setups. In newer version I have the common setup code instead of multiple setups.

I have to write htaccess rule to redirect old URL's into new version URL. All the requests are POST request so I have to redirect without affecting the POST data.

**Problem**

**Old Setup URL**

http://example.com/client1/a_report/index.php/rest_server/index
http://example.com/client2/a_report/index.php/rest_server/index

**I want these URL's need to be redirected to the latest one**

http://example.com/commonsetup/index.php/rest_server/index

I tried this following code it is not working as expected

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^client1/a_report(.*) http://example.com/commonsetup/$1 [NC,L,P]
RewriteRule ^client2/a_report(.*) http://example.com/commonsetup/$1 [NC,L,P]
```

This code is working but it's giving the Wrong URL. In this case the POST will becomes GET. This also I need to fix

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/client1/
RewriteRule (.*) /commonsetup/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The result I got in the browser

> Not Found The requested URL
>   /commonsetup/client1/a_report/index.php/rest_server/index was not
>   found on this server.

The required output is

> /commonsetup/index.php/rest_server/index

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: POST data is not transferred after a redirect. Do it via curl on server side.

Comment: I have 50 setups I have to getaway from this that's why the commoncode in that place. Okay how to redirect

Comment: As long as your rewrite rule doesn't actually redirect the page (but just rewrites the path internally), your POST data is preserved because it's still using the same HTTP request. - gathered from google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above `POST` data will be lost if doing an external redirect.

You have 3 options to preserve POST data:

1. Don't do redirect and do an internal rewrite only
2. Enable `mod_proxy` and use `P` flag for proxying the request
3. Write server side code e.g. using `curl` and pass-on POST data to destination

Try this rule for **internal rewrite** in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:client2|client1)/a_report/(.+)$ /commonsetup/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: how to fix the error what i got in my attempts. I wrote the rewrite rule that's giving error

Comment: You are little close like my second attempt . I got this message from the browser The requested URL /commonsetup/client1 was not found on this server. But I want the URL like this /commonsetup/index.php/rest_server/index

Comment: If you original URL has `index.php` like `http://example.com/client1/a_report/index.php/rest_server/index` then it will rewritten to: `http://example.com/commonsetup/index.php/rest_server/index`

Comment: Actually I had a mistake that I corrected, try it now.